# Best mapping between 2 sequences

Tags: algorithm

I have two sequences of items:

> S1 = [ A B C D E F ]
>
> S2 = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]

And I can determine "similarity" for each pair of items (s1, s2) as a number (for example on scale 0 to 10).

I want to find a mapping between S1/S2 items, such that ordering of each sequence is preserved and sum of "similarity" values between mapped items is maximum. It is not required that all S1/S2 items are part of mapping.

Example:

```
[     A B C D   E F     ]
[ 1 2 3     4 5   6 7 8 ]
```

In example above, mapping 'A on 3', 'D on 4' and 'F on 6' gives overall maximum "similarity".

Are there any existing problems (/algorithms) this could be turned into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Smith–Waterman algorithm, which is traditional used for determining similar regions between two strings of nucleic acid sequences or protein sequences, should be perfect:

> Smith–Waterman algorithm aligns two sequences by matches/mismatches (also known as substitutions), insertions, and deletions. Both insertions and deletions are the operations that introduce gaps, which are represented by dashes. The Smith–Waterman algorithm has several steps:
>
> - Determine the substitution matrix and the gap penalty scheme. A substitution matrix assigns each pair of items (s1, s2) a score for match or mismatch. Usually matches get positive scores, whereas mismatches get relatively lower scores. A gap penalty function determines the score cost for opening or extending gaps. It is suggested that users choose the appropriate scoring system based on the goals. In addition, it is also a good practice to try different combinations of substitution matrices and gap penalties.
> - Initialize the scoring matrix. The dimensions of the scoring matrix are 1+length of each sequence respectively. All the elements of the first row and the first column are set to 0. The extra first row and first column make it possible to align one sequence to another at any position, and setting them to 0 makes the terminal gap free from penalty.
> - Scoring. Score each element from left to right, top to bottom in the matrix, considering the outcomes of substitutions (diagonal scores) or adding gaps (horizontal and vertical scores). If none of the scores are positive, this element gets a 0. Otherwise the highest score is used and the source of that score is recorded.
> - Traceback. Starting at the element with the highest score, traceback based on the source of each score recursively, until 0 is encountered. The segments that have the highest similarity score based on the given scoring system is generated in this process. To obtain the second best local alignment, apply the traceback process starting at the second highest score outside the trace of the best alignment.

Just choose the substitution matrix to match yours

> And I can determine "similarity" for each pair of items (s1, s2) as a number (for example on scale 0 to 10).

and set the gap and no match penalty to zero

> I want to find a mapping between S1/S2 items, such that ordering of each sequence is preserved and sum of "similarity" values between mapped items is maximum. It is not required that all S1/S2 items are part of mapping.

More information can be found at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm#Scoring_matrix

Comment: I think you and mingaleg are both correct since I didn't specify any gap penalty.

Comment: I must confess that I didn't review mingaleg's answer when I posted, I've upvote theirs to reflect that both answers are valid

Answer (score 2):

The problem you described looks like [Longest Common Subsequence Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) variation.

Use this recurrent relation instead of original:

```
ans[i][j] = max(
    ans[i-1][j],
    ans[i][j-1],
    ans[i-1][j-1] + similarity(S1[i], S2[j])
)
```

Comment: This appears to match Ryan's answer as "Simplified Smith-Waterman algorithm with linear gap penalty when that penalty is 0", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm#Linear